# How will the update from DO-260A to DO-260B improve safety and efficiency in air traffic management significantly?

Tags: radar, ads-b, surveillance

From what I know, the version update from DO-260A and DO-260B offers new features such as on-ground vs airborne source selection logic, ADS-B failure annunciation, the split of the quality indicators between horizontal and vertical component, the addition of GVA and SDA, etc. In comparison with the previous versions, it is expected that the latest version could at least increase efficiency and safety in utilizing airspace.

Assuming country “X” has implemented DO-260A as their minimum standards for its surveillance infrastructure and it could accommodate up to 1000 planes every hour. Then it decided to update to DO-260B and could accommodate up to 2000 planes every hour.  And yet I ponder with all of these new advancements in DO-260B, is there:

1. A way that I can estimate and measure quantitatively based on the update? (Assuming that DO-260B **does** improve safety and efficiency in air traffic management)
2. With the quality indicators in DO-260B, how are those used in the process of that estimation?
3. A website that analyzes safety and efficiency quantitatively on air traffic management, specifically after changing MOPS such as from DO-260A to DO-260B ?

    Thank you in advance.

---

Source:

1. https://atl.aero/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/ADS-B-Out-Instalaltion.pdf

2. RTCA DO-260B DRAFT Version 4.2